# How to validate a winform textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textbox in my windows form application and I am trying to use the following condition to see if they match:

```
Can only enter A-F(a-f) and 0-9
Backspace/Delete/Arrow keys are allowed
```

I have the following code-behind (default text is `FFFFFF` on form load):

```
private void tbHex_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"^[a-fA-F0-9");
    MatchCollection mc = rx.Matches(tbHex.Text);
    if (mc.Count > 0) //if anything other than what is asked is entered...
    {
        MessageBox.Show("NO!");
    }
}
```

What is happening when the form load is, I am displayed with the "NO!" message box.

How can I modify so the user can ONLY enter the valid characters/keys and also does the same validation when pasting into the textbox as well as entering it character by character.

Comment: Try using a [`MaskedTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of a `TextBox`.

Comment: Is that missing `]` (`@"^[a-fA-F0-9"`)

Comment: This is a UI nightmare. Much better to supress any invalid characters than hitting the user with a messagebox. Check out the many examples at the right --->

Comment: Definitely not hitting them with messagebox. This was an example.

Answer (score 1):

Text changed happens at form load when the text is originally set.  It will also fire at every character keystroke.  You could use an event such as `Validating` or `Validated` if you only want it to only fire after user changes the text.